# Coloring the terminal prompt text issue

Tags: command-line

I've learned a neat trick in school to make your terminal prompt text look more pretty, eg.

```
export PS1="(\h) \u \w "
```

gives me

```
(brendt-ubuntu) brendt ~
```

The issue happens when I try to color these things, some weird text overflow bug appears:

This is without colors

[image]

This is with colors

```
(export PS1="\e[1;34m(\h)\e[m \u \e[1;34m\w \e[m")
```

[image]

Are there any fixes for this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using proper color coding:

```
PS1="\[\033[01;34m\](\h)\[\033[00m\] \u \[\033[01;34m\]\w \[\033[00m\]"
```